# Why do I get 'use of uninitialized value' warnings even though I return a value from Try::Tiny's finally block?

Tags: perl, assignment-operator

It is unclear to me why the piece of code below gives me the error:

`Use of uninitialized value in addition (+) at combined_op_test.pl line 12.`

I expect the value of `$success_count` to increment by the value returned from the subroutine on each iteration.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.014;
use Try::Tiny;

my $success_count = 0;

for ( 1..10 ) {
    $success_count += error_causing_sub();
}

sub error_causing_sub {
   try {
        die ("Error.");
   } catch { 
   } finally {
        if (@_) { 
            say "Error occured.";
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            say "Error did not occur.";
            return 1;
        }
   };
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the [CAVEATS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Try::Tiny#CAVEATS) section of the documentation, the `return` does not return from the sub, it returns from `finally`:

> `return` returns from the `try` block, not from the parent `sub` (note that this is also how `eval` works, but not how `TryCatch` works):
>
> ```
> sub parent_sub {
>   try {
>     die;
>   }
>   catch {
>     return;
>   };
>   say "this text WILL be displayed, even though an exception is thrown";
> }
> ```

As [@simbabque notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45865324/use-of-uninitialized-value-when-returning-from-perl-subroutine/45865373#comment78689349_45865373), the return value of `finally` is ignored. If the `try` fails, the return value of `catch` is relevant, and it's empty:

> The return value of the `catch` block is not ignored, so if testing the result of the expression for truth on success, be sure to return a false value from the `catch` block: ...

The following code looks more logical to me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.014;
use Try::Tiny;

my $success_count = 0;

for ( 1..10 ) {
    $success_count += error_causing_sub();
}

say $success_count;

sub error_causing_sub {
    my $ret;
    try {
        die ("Error.") if rand(1) < 0.5;
        say "Error did not occur.";
        $ret = 1;
    } catch {
        say "Error occured.";
        $ret = 0;
    };

    return $ret;
}
```

In addition, AFAIK, [the issues with `eval` that made `Try::Tiny` relevant were fixed in 5.14](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perl5140delta.pod#Exception-Handling). So, you may be better off just using it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.014;

my $success_count = 0;

$success_count += error_causing_sub() for 1 .. 10;

say $success_count;

sub error_causing_sub {
    my $ret;
    eval {
        die ("Error.") if rand(1) < 0.5;
        say "Error did not occur.";
        $ret = 1;
    } or do {
        say "Error occured.";
        $ret = 0;
    };

    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: That's not fully it. The RV of the `finally` is ignored. If it fails, the RV of `catch` is relevant, and it's empty. No time to write my own answer. You can see by changing to `catch { 1 }`

Comment: 5.14 fixed `if ($@)`. That last snippet doesn't use `if ($@)`, so it would have worked even before 5.14.